# Pass a value to my controller with $.get() javascript to my controller method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is my goal:

I'm trying to display the details of an event in my modal.
For that, I execute a javascript script which returns to the "GetEventsDetails" method of my "Event" controller with the id of the event.

When I debug with Chrome, I see the id pass except that in my controller, the value is always 0.

I do not really understand why, I checked a lot on the net and everything seems right on my side!

Is it because I do not use an ajax call?

Thank you in advance!

```
    function GetEventsDetails(id) {

         //$('#myModal').find('.modal-title').text("Details ");

         $.get("@Url.Action("GetEventsDetails", "Events")/" + id,
             function (data) {
                 $('.modal-body').html(data);

             })
         $('#myModal').show();
    }
</script>
```

}

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetEventsDetails(int Zkp)
{

    ViewBag.sessionv = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("idMember");
    FileMakerRestClient client = new FileMakerRestClient(serverName, fileName, userName, password);
    var toFind = new Models.EventsLines { Zkp = Zkp };
    var results = await client.FindAsync(toFind);

    bool isEmpty = !results.Any();
    if (isEmpty)
    {
        return View();
    }

    Models.EventsLines oEventViewModel = new Models.EventsLines();

    oEventViewModel = results.ToList().First();

    Console.WriteLine(oEventViewModel);

    return PartialView(oEventViewModel);
}
```

Comment: If you have the default routing, your parameter name should be `id` for that to work

Comment: Try modify this: GetEventsDetails(int id), my friend :))

Comment: *"Is it because I do not use an ajax call?"*  You are using an ajax call.  `$.get()` is an ajax call.  If you copy the url that you are making with the get() and paste it into your browser, does it work?  If it does not, this is not an issue with javascript, and is an issue with your backend

Comment: I don't use asp so maybe I'm missing something, but why are you using concatenation instead of using the data param in jQuery's `$.get()`? https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Thanks guys! I just had to put (int id) as you said.. I didnt know if was an obligation but thanks :D

Comment: Quick question, when it opens the modal, it has to load the data which works great but for 5sec (the time to take the data and load in on the screen) it displays "{Html.RenderPartial("GetEventsDetails", item);} " in my modal... Is it possible to hide this?
Its not cool for the user experience!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
         function GetEventsDetails(id) {

             //$('#myModal').find('.modal-title').text("Details ");
             var urlpath = "/ Events / GetEventsDetails /" + id;
             $.get(urlpath, function (data) {
                 $('.modal-body').html(data);

             });

         $('#myModal').show();
    }
    </script>
```

And Your Controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetEventsDetails(int id)
```